# What is the use of NiFi Counters?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I didn't find any documentation related to nifi counters.I Want to know how to use this feature and purpose of this feature.

Comment: this is the user guide....https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html

Answer (score 6):

Counters are a way for a processor to track how many times some event occurred, mostly for monitoring purposes. There is a method in the ProcessSession:

```
void adjustCounter(String name, long delta, boolean immediate);
```

So calling this method with ("myCounter", 1, true) would increment the count of "myCounter" by 1, or create the counter if it didn't exist. Counters are not persistent and will be reset on restart. An example is in the syslog processors which increment a counter for each syslog message received.

See discussion here:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/50622/apache-nifi-what-are-counters-in-nifi.html

Comment: Got an idea about counters, but how and where can I see those incremented value of events, counter section does not load anything in its page.
Any other configuration needed to get those counter value of the processors?